# How to handle 2 almost similar components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, factorization

In a page, I have 2 components which do almost the same thing, although one of them has a functionnality that the other has not.

Consider these 2 components:

#### Component 1

```
<template>
  <div>Something</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Component 1',
  methods () {
    someMethod () {}
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Component 2

```
<template>
  <div>Something</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Component 2',
  methods () {
    someMethod () {},
    someMethodSpecificToComponent2 () {}
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, both components are pretty similar, which makes me want to factorize them into 1 component. However, if I do so, the method `someMethodSpecificToComponent2` would sometimes be useless since it is specific to 1 use case, which I believe is antipattern. If I don't factorize them, there will be some duplicated code, which is also a thing best avoided.

Also, I could put `someMethodSpecificToComponent2` in a mixin, and import this mixin in the component that needs this function, but I am quite unsure this is the best solution.

What is the best way to handle 2 almost identical components, whether it is duplication, factorization with some parts left unused, factorization with a mixin, or anything else?

Comment: mixin solution is both clean and simple. what's your concern? nothing wrong with it. or extend Component1 methods in Component2 with `someMethodSpecificToComponent2`.

Comment: It just feels weird to me. It looks like a hack, a workaround, because I haven't seen anyone use mixins this way. But that's nothing more than a feeling, which is why I am still open to this solution. If I don't have knowledge of any specific reason why the mixin solution would be bad I might end up using it!